# Problématique connecteur spatial et temporel

Tags: vocabulaire

J'ai une petite question concernant le texte qui suit. À vos yeux, existe-t-il un connecteur spatial ou temporel dans cette phrase :

> Avant de finir, Julien revint à la préméditation, à son repentir

Je crois voir un connecteur temporel dans « Avant de finir », et un connecteur spatial dans « revint ».

Mais je n'en suis pas sûr. Pourriez-vous m'aiguiller s'il vous plaît ?

Comment: "Revint" est just le passé simple du verbe "revenir".

Comment: Languages don't have many ready-to-hand ways to talk about temporal relationships. For example, "avant" literally means "at the front". In English "before" means the same. So our temporal words are just repurposed spatial words anyway. We operate in constant metaphor. Of course, you can go to the Greek to get technical distinctions if you want (chronological, etc), but they are recherché.

Answer (score 2):

Un connecteur sert à situer dans le temps ou dans l'espace une action par rapport à une autre. Ce sont en général des adverbes ou des conjonctions.

***Revint*** ne peut pas jouer ce rôle pour deux raisons. La premier est qu'étant lui-même un verbe, il indique une action, la deuxième est que le verbe revenir est à prendre ici au sens figuré et qu'il n'y a donc pas de déplacement, rien de spatial. Tout se passe dans la tête de Julien Sorel. On ne trouve en conséquence pas de connecteur spatial dans cet extrait de phrase. Si *préméditation* et *repentir* avaient été des lieux, *à* aurait pu être un connecteur de ce type.